# "Argument #2 should be an array"

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I am using the Nova theme from elegantthemes.com.  At the bottom of the page is an error:

> Warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an
>   array in /wp-content/themes/Nova/home.php on line 21

Line 12-25 of of home.php is:

```
<?php
    $pagesContent = array();
    $i=0;

    $home_pages_num = count(get_option('nova_home_pages'));

    $arr = array( 'post_type' => 'page',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'post__in' => (array) array_map( 'intval', get_option('nova_home_pages') ),
                'posts_per_page' => (int) $home_pages_num );

    query_posts($arr);
?>
```

Line 21 is :

```
'post__in' => (array) array_map( 'intval', get_option('nova_home_pages') ),
```

Can you determine what the issue is?

I no longer have a paid subscription to elegantthemes.com

Comment: Seems like `get_option('nova_home_pages')` does not return an array.

Comment: Can you `var_dump(get_option('nova_home_pages'))` and see if it is an array?

Comment: oh, I realise i actually have no Pages, only Posts, could this be related?

Answer (score 0):

> Can you determine what the issue is?

```
get_option('nova_home_pages')
```

is not an array, so the warning is thrown.